# WCF set Thread.CurrentPrincipal via IHttpModule

Tags: .net, wcf, authentication, ihttpmodule

I have wcf + rest web service with aspNetCompatibility = "true".
To provide custom authentication I wrote asp.net http module : IHttpModule. The code is pretty simple: just assign some principal to Thread.CurrentPrinicpal property.

During the method execution I still get 'empty / default' principal as value of Thread.CurrentPrincipal. Also I noticed there are different thread ids (Thread.CurrentThread) in module and operation execution. I have a suggestion that wcf provide a new thread  to execute operation, but haven't found any proofs.

So the question: Am I correct? Does wcf allow to control that behavior?
I'm confused here because creating new thread will automatically move principal to new thread. Hence wcf 'clean' them..

The same issue with principalPermissionMode="None".

I would appreciate for any ideas!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

IMO - thread will receive the Principal when you run it from thread with already sat one.

Wcf does manage the threads in its own way (partially controlled by InstanceMode - PerCall, PerSession, ...). So they will not propogate your thread details.

May be you should consider to use another model for authentication. See this post for more details about custom authentication: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2010/07/21/odata-and-authentication-part-6-custom-basic-authentication.aspx

Comment: You are right with the first sentence. Actually I solved by IAuthorizationPolicy with wcf. But as I wrote I want to get clear understanding why it's work in this way and do we have any settings to control that behavior?